# Adding fields in a type versus creating new type in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I own an application and for its activity log I want to use elastic search.
The application has many deployments (~500). There are a bunch of fields for activity log lines common across all deployments.
However, for each deployment, there are a small (<10) number of fields that are specific to that deployment.

To create a mapping type for my activity_log index, I see a few options:

- Create a single mapping type, with all fields from all deployments. of course, the documents sent for a particular deployment will only contain the common fields and the fields specific to that deployment.
- Create a type per deployment, containing only the common fields and the deployment specific fields
- Create a single type, but put custom fields as array of nested "field-name:value" documents

What is the recommended approach for such a use case? I also want to be able to visualize the data in kibana and I am not sure how that would work with nested documents

Comment: in my opinion it is related to the complexity of those specific fields.. from my experience I would recommend you to go with option 2 that will make it easier to visualize the data for each deployment separately but it will cost you more memory and will make it harder to combine queries from different deployment. if the fields are simple you i would choose option number 1. i would avoid option 3 because it will limit you to change the index options on specific fields in the array such as times on more

Comment: @nivpenso It occurred to me that I could simply have a field with an object type with dynamic mapping. Since my per-deployment custom fields are really only string key value pairs, that should be fine, right ?

Comment: Yes it should be fine